# SQL LEFT JOIN with WHERE statement after is not displaying unconnected rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, left-join

I’m trying to return all of the course_codes from my curriculum table while also displaying a specific student’s progress in each course. The transcript table holds all the courses the student has taken or is taking and has their grade is those courses.
When I use the below code, I almost get the output I’m looking for (All courses codes in the curriculum and the student’s grade from the transcript table if they have taken a course that is in the curriculum. The courses the student hasn’t taken yet should display an output of null in any field from the transcript table). But I need to return the grades for a specific student and not all of the students. The query below does not take that into account.

```
SELECT DISTINCT curriculum.Course_Code, transcript.Course_Grade, transcript.Course_Comp, transcript.CWID 
FROM curriculum 
LEFT JOIN transcript 
ON curriculum.Course_Code = transcript.Course_Code ;
```

Result: [Query with no WHERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9m5E.png)

The next query is the same as the one above but tries to return the grades for a specific student by adding WHERE transcript.CWID = “C38475920”. The output of the query is only the class that are in both the student’s transcript and curriculum.

```
SELECT DISTINCT curriculum.Course_Code, transcript.Course_Grade, transcript.Course_Comp, transcript.CWID 
FROM curriculum 
LEFT JOIN transcript 
ON curriculum.Course_Code = transcript.Course_Code 
WHERE transcript.CWID = "C38475920";
```

Result: [Query with WHERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25xYh.png)

How can I get a result of all the course_codes from the curriculum and a student’s grades in those courses with a CWID of "C38475920"?

Example: If a student with a transcript.CWID of “C38475920" has completed 5 courses in the curriculum and there are a total of 10 courses in the curriculum. All 10 course_codes in the curriculum will be returned with 5 courses that the student has taken showing grade values and 5 courses the student hasn’t taken yet showing NULL values in transcript.COURSE_GRADE, transcript.COURSE_COMP, etc…

Comment: To get true LEFT JOIN result, move the transcript.CWID from WHERE to ON. As it is now you get regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a LEFT JOIN ON, a WHERE or INNER JOIN that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL removes any rows with introduced NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the condition on the `left join`ed table from the `where` clause to the `on` part of the `join`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM curriculum c
LEFT JOIN transcript t 
    ON c.Course_Code = t.Course_Code and t.CWID = "C38475920";
```

Conditions in the `where` clause are *mandatory*, so the way you phrased the query actually turned the `left join` to an `inner join`: if a curriculum had no transcript, the `where` clause evicts the corresponding row.

Answer (score 1):

The `where` condition is applied after the tables are joined and the rows returned. If you want to join on a subset of the rows, you could have the condition in the `on` clause:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT curriculum.Course_Code, transcript.Course_Grade, transcript.Course_Comp, transcript.CWID 
FROM curriculum 
LEFT JOIN transcript 
ON curriculum.Course_Code = transcript.Course_Code AND transcript.CWID = "C38475920";
```